# Boot Camp issue

Tags: hard-drive, windows, startup

My Windows system is a folder in the Startup Disk PrefPane, but shows an hard drive icon on my desktop. How do I turn it into a hard drive icon in the start up disk? I've tried everything but haven't been able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application that comes with your Mac (in /Applications/Utilities) called Boot Camp Assistant. Launch that and follow the instructions provided on screen.

I am guessing that you have a disk image file of the Windows installer on your computer. If you double-click on it it will open up into a virtual hard drive. If that is the case Boot Camp Assistant will use the Windows installer file you have and ask you for a USB thumb drive (8GB minimum size) that it can format (erase completely) and set up to act as your Windows installer.

It will then reboot your Mac and prompt you to rearrange your hard drive's formatting to make room for Windows. Assuming you have enough room on your hard drive this is completely non-destructive and leaves your Mac HD a little smaller but otherwise untouched. Then it will install Windows on your Mac. Assuming you have the right version of Windows for the version of Mac and Mac O/S that you have. More info on all of that would get your questions answered better.